# how to play video downloaded from server in SD-card

Tags: android, video, android-intent, android-mediaplayer

i have a file downloaded from server and save it in DOWNLOAD folder

how can i play it from default player of android with code ?

with actin code ? like this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "tarsnak.3gp")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the 'type' wrong.
Use following code.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);                      
i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "tarsnak.3gp")),"video/*");
startActivity(i);
```